# calculating Margin for each item with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to position different DIVs with different widths along different X Axes, (50%,30% …)
So i tried this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.axis').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.css('margin-left', -(startWidth / 2) + 'px');
});
});
```

CSS:

```
#item_1 {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 50%;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Somehow, it is not working yet…

```
<div class="axis" id="item_1"></div>
<div class="axis" id="item_2"></div>
<div class="axis" id="item_3"></div>
```

Here is a JFiddle that shows the problem, i would like to have the ITEMS Centered on a X Axis…

https://jsfiddle.net/gtpadmy2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JS.
Just add a translation that fixes the half margin to your CSS:

```
.axis {
  // other properties
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gtpadmy2/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much… If i write it like this, I can´t get it work somehow…

Do I mess up the brakes?

Comment: Can you maybe update your question with the new code?

Comment: Do you mean centered on the **X Axis**?

Comment: Oh haha. This makes it a lot more simple. You don't need any JS at all.